# Inno Setup CompareStr returns non-zero, even though strings are the same

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

```pascal
function DebugIsEnabled: Boolean;
var
  A: AnsiString;
  U: String;
begin
  AppLoc := RemoveQuotes(CurrentAppLoc(''))
  if Standalone then
    LoadStringFromFile(AppLoc + '\Default.ini', A)
  else
    LoadStringFromFile(AppLoc + '\FrankenStein\Default.ini', A);
  U := A;
  if CompareStr(U, 'IsCombo=TRUE') = 0 then
    Result := True
  else
    Result := False
end;
```

Somehow the check functions don't work the way I need them to. And I can't pin down what I did wrong. The `CompareStr` seems to return `20` instead of `0`. I have made a similar tool a few years ago and the same check functions worked like a charm (Tasks were shown/hidden correctly).

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that there are some whitespace in the file, like a new-line sequence at the end of the line.

Try to trim all the leading and trailing whitespaces using [`Trim` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_trim) before comparing:

```pascal
U := Trim(A);
if CompareStr(U, 'IsCombo=TRUE') = 0 then
```

---

Side note: The trailing `if else` statement can be simplified to:

```pascal
Result := (CompareStr(U, 'IsCombo=TRUE') = 0);
```

---

As we can deduct from your would-be answer, your file is obviously an INI file. You never told us!

Your original code loads whole file. And then it treats it like there is a single line in the file only (the `IsCombo=TRUE`). Obviously there's not only one line in the file, there's at least the section header `[Link]`. But how could we know from your question?

So the answer to your actual question is: **The strings are not the same!** The `U` (and `A`) contains a whole file, while you compare that to a single randomly chosen line of the file only.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this. Posting all three checks, since I ended up not sing `CompareStr` at all (it behaved really weird, and couldn't figure out what I was doing wrong)

```
function DebugIsEnabled: Boolean;
var
  A: AnsiString;
  U: String;
begin
if Standalone then
  AppLoc := RemoveQuotes(CurrentAppLoc(''))
else
  AppLoc := RemoveQuotes(CurrentAppLoc('')) + '\FrankenStein\';
    result := GetIniString('Link', 'IsCombo', 'TRUE', AppLoc + 'Default.ini') = 'TRUE'
end;

function VidIsEnabled: Boolean;
var
  A: AnsiString;
  U: String;
begin
if Standalone then
  AppLoc := RemoveQuotes(CurrentAppLoc(''))
else
  AppLoc := RemoveQuotes(CurrentAppLoc('')) + '\FrankenStein\';
  result := IniKeyExists('Section', 'Key', AppLoc + 'Base.ini')
end;

function UmbrellaIsEnabled: Boolean;
var
  A: AnsiString;
  U: String;
begin
if Standalone then
  AppLoc := RemoveQuotes(CurrentAppLoc(''))
else
  AppLoc := RemoveQuotes(CurrentAppLoc('')) + '\FrankenStein\';
  result := GetIniString('Config', 'Umbrella',  true', AppLoc + 'Default.ini') = 'true'
end;
```

As for `Log`, I've never used that, so I couldn't figure out how to trigger it. I know it's lame, but...

Comment: While this answer may solve your actual problem, it does not not answer your question, which is *"CompareStr returns non-zero, even though strings are the same"*

Comment: Yes, that's why I didn't mark it as a solution. The problem with `CompareStr` is still there. I'm sure the strings are the same, still, somehow, they don't result in `0`. I can also share my `CurrentAppLoc` function, in case that one's faulty, but, as I said, it works everywhere else in the script

Comment: I've explained that the strings are **not the same** in my answer.